# How to use ONNX models for inference in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, user-defined-functions, onnx

I have trained a model for text classification using `huggingface/transformers`, then I exported it using the built-in ONNX functionality.

Now, I'd like to use it for inference on millions of texts (around 100 millions of sentences). My idea is to put all the texts in a Spark `DataFrame`, then bundle the `.onnx` model into a Spark UDF, and run inference that way, on a Spark cluster.

Is there a better way of doing this? Am I doing things "the right way"?

Comment: I have edited my answer to also include the MLflow approach. Note that I have not used it myself, but according to their documentation, it should also be doable. I hope that either of the solutions would help you solve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you are aware of and/or allowed to use [SynapseML](https://microsoft.github.io/SynapseML/), due to the requirements (cf. "SynapseML requires Scala 2.12, Spark 3.0+, and Python 3.6+," as of today, per the landing page), but SynapseML *does have* support for [ONNX Inference on Spark](https://microsoft.github.io/SynapseML/docs/features/onnx/ONNX%20-%20Inference%20on%20Spark/). This could probably be the cleanest solution for you.

**EDIT.** Also, MLflow has support for [exporting a `python_function` model as an Apache Spark UDF](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/models.html#export-a-python-function-model-as-an-apache-spark-udf). With MLflow, you save your model in, say, the ONNX format, log/register the model via [`mlflow.onnx.log_model`](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.onnx.html#mlflow.onnx.log_model), and later retrieve it in the `mlflow.pyfunc.spark_udf` call via its path, i.e., `models:/<model-name>/<model-version>`.